# Passing Variables From Embedded Web Browser to Application

Tags: c#, javascript, wpf, winforms

I'd like to know whether it's possible to pass data from a C# application (e.g. WPF) to a web-page (i.e. an HTML page with Javascript) in an embedded Web Browser. If so, how?

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish? Why don't you just pass the variables to PHP? The question is too broad, but yes, it is possible.

Comment: I need to interface with some code written in Javascript. What I was wondering specifically is how I might pass a "var" in Javascript to a C# application which is displaying the webpage containing the Javascript in a Web Browser object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can invoke methods (and thus pass data) in your C# code from JavaScript using `Window.external`. Try googling for this keyword, more information will come up quickly.

[This blog post](https://blogs.msdn.com/b/wpf/archive/2011/05/27/how-does-wpf-webbrowser-control-handle-window-external-notify.aspx) has a good, simple (WPF-)example how to invoke a C# method from JavaScript using `Window.external`. Another keyword here is `[System.Runtime.InteropServices.ComVisibleAttribute(True)]`. You have to mark your handler class with this attribute to be accessible from JavaScript. And finally you tell your WebBrowser control about the handler class via its `ObjectForScripting` property.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it seems interesting. Currently we were using anchor hooks to invoke calls and the data passed on the URL (in the query). This seems interesting, especially if the C# can return back data.